# Return an array once the for loop is finished in typescript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

I am pushing some values into an array using for loop. I want to return this array once the for loop is finished with all values that were pushed using for loop. 
I am calling this function from some other code. But I am getting an empty array. I understand that it is due to async function but I am not sure how to fix this.

```
 public async getNames() {
    let accounts: string[] = [];
    await this.waitForElementToBeVisible(this.eleNames.get(0));
    let num: number = await this.eleNames.count();
    for (let i: number = 0; i < num; i++) {
      console.log("inside for loop");
      await accounts.push(await this.eleNames.get(i).getText());
    }

    return accounts;
  }
```

and I am calling this getNames from other code which is below

```js
     actualNames = await dashboardPage.getInstance.getNames();
```

but it returns an empty array.

Comment: Is you eleNames.get method async or not? Because you have one awaited and one non awaited call to that method.

Comment: Yes it is async.

Comment: Why don't you await it on second line?

Comment: you mean on the console.log ? i am just using it to print the names, i will remove it afterwords

Comment: No, inside this.waitForElementToBeVisible

Answer (score 0):

Try below code use `Promise`

```
public async getNames(): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise<any>( (resolve)=>{

        let accounts = [];
        await this.waitForElementToBeVisible(this.eleNames.get(0));
        let num: number = await this.eleNames.count();
        for (let i: number = 0; i < num; i++) {
          console.log("inside for loop");
          accounts = await this.addDataToAccounts(accounts, this.eleNames.get(i).getText());
        }

        resolve(accounts); // Use resolve instead of return for new Promise.
    })
}
```

Create new method `addDataToAccounts` for push data to accounts and return new `Promise` as below.

```
public addDataToAccounts(accounts: any, data: string): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise<any>( (resolve)=> {
        resolve(accounts.push(data));
    });
}
```

Refer [this link](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html) for more about `async awit`

Comment: i tried doing it, but it's showing error for all awaits

Comment: That is because `getNames()` returning promise object, Please try to add `async` on method where you'r calling this `actualNames = await dashboardPage.getInstance.getNames();`